# Getting selected security provider

Tags: java, security

The API:

```
        Provider[] p = Security.getProviders();
```

Will tell me all the providers in the JVM.  But how do I determine what is the provider the JVM will try to use and what provider the JVM is actually using?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The method `System.getProviders()` gives you the providers in their preference order. So the first provider is the default one.

[Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Security.html#getProviders%28%29)

Comment: But how do I find out which provide is being actually used?

Comment: Depends on the algorithm you use.